# Using "from" as a kwarg key in pymongo's runcommand

Tags: python, mongodb, clone, pymongo, mongo-collection

I am attempting to use pymongo to clone a collection from a remote mongo instance, from the [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/cloneCollection/#dbcmd.cloneCollection) cloning a collection requires the `cloneCollection` command,

```
{ cloneCollection: "<collection>", from: "<hostname>", query: { <query> } }
```

and to [run this command in pymongo](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/database.html?#pymongo.database.Database.command) I need to specify the additional parameters of the command as kwargs like this:

```
db.command("cloneCollection","db_name.collection_name", from = "localhost:27017")
```

But since `from` is a reserved keyword in python I cannot use it as a keyword.
An alternative is to pass the command as a python dict like this:

```
db.command({"cloneCollection":"db_name.collection_name", "from":"localhost:27017"})
```

However in this case the order is not preserved, and I get this error

```
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: command {'from': 'localhost:27017', 'cloneCollection': 'db_name.collection_name'} failed: no such cmd: from
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how pymongo uses the dictionary, you might be able to use [OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) (from the builtin collections module). This is only available from python 2.7, but there are backports available for python 2.4 onwards.

In this case you could do something like:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
config = OrderedDict((
    ("cloneCollection", "db_name.collection_name"),
    ("from", "localhost:27017"),
))
db.command(config)
```

Answer (score 2):

Figured that I can use [bson.son.SON](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/bson/son.html) to create a SON object (a subclass of dict that maintains ordering of keys), pymongo also does this internally when we pass arguments or python dict to pymongo commands,

```
from bson.son import SON
db.command(SON([("cloneCollection","db_name.collection_name"), ("from","localhost:27017")]))
```